# Post/photo reporting in ios app

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am working on an iOS app which allows users to create posts that include photos. In doing this, I became aware that I will need to include a feature to allow users to report a photo in order for the app to be accepted by apple.

Does anyone know of a service or a framework that I can implement to receive reports for posts?

If it matters, I'm using parse.com as my backend.

Comment: What about AWS? I think amazon's service is cheaper.

Comment: Instead of parse? Or to do the reports?

Comment: Yup, AWS has cloud service and you can post data on it.

Comment: Okay. Do you have any ideas for allowing users to submit reports?